# two columns, click on the left shows result on the right

Tags: css, html

I would like to create two divs. one on the left side containing titles, and one on right side containing some text relative to each title.

I also would like to get it working like http://www.francefilierepeche.fr/projets/carte-interactive-projets/ but with clickable text or divs on the left instead of the map.

I have found the tips on `[https://jsfiddle.net/hoq0djwc/][2]` but when i try to put each part on a separated div, the right column text do nomore appear.

I can use only html and css as i want to show this in a drupal page.

Can any of you help me ?

Comment: please share your code directly in the question. Also you need to use some javascript to get what you want (if you don't want to reload the page). I guess that drupal comes with some jquery already installed so you can put in your page some js too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple sense, this could be called as a **Tab Behaviour**. Use the `href` to populate the `id` of the tab and hide everything and show only the respected one:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".item").hide();
  $(".col-12:first-child a").click(function () {
    $(".item:visible").hide();
    $($(this).attr("href")).show();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
h3 {font-weight: 600; margin: 0 0 10px;}
.cols {overflow: hidden;}
.cols .col-12 {width: 50%; float: left;}
ul li, ul li a {display: block;}
ul li a {padding: 5px 10px; text-decoration: none;}
ul li a:hover {background-color: #ccf;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<div class="cols">
  <div class="col-12">
    <h3>Left</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#item-1">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#item-2">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#item-3">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#item-4">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#item-5">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <h3>Right</h3>
    <div class="item" id="item-1">Item 1 Content</div>
    <div class="item" id="item-2">Item 2 Content</div>
    <div class="item" id="item-3">Item 3 Content</div>
    <div class="item" id="item-4">Item 4 Content</div>
    <div class="item" id="item-5">Item 5 Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Using Pure CSS version:**

This is the same as your own code. I would probably propose a few changes like:

- Have the same class.
- Give the unique `id`.
- Make sure the link is followed.
- The `id` should match the `href`.

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
h3 {font-weight: 600; margin: 0 0 10px;}
.cols {overflow: hidden;}
.cols .col-12 {width: 50%; float: left;}
ul li, ul li a {display: block;}
ul li a {padding: 5px 10px; text-decoration: none;}
ul li a:hover {background-color: #ccf;}
.item {display: none;}
.item:target {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="cols">
  <div class="col-12">
    <h3>Left</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#item-1">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#item-2">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#item-3">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#item-4">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#item-5">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <h3>Right</h3>
    <div class="item" id="item-1">Item 1 Content</div>
    <div class="item" id="item-2">Item 2 Content</div>
    <div class="item" id="item-3">Item 3 Content</div>
    <div class="item" id="item-4">Item 4 Content</div>
    <div class="item" id="item-5">Item 5 Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi,
Thank you a lot for your answer, this will help me a lot.
Now : in your code, when "Item 1" is clicked, i get on the right div "Item 1 Content" But what if i want to get on the div's title: "Right: Item x" where x takes the number of the selected element, and then, i will get the content?

As you see on the example i want to make like, the right div's title gets a value that changes depending on the selected region.

Comment: @Dhia If there are two things to be changed, you **need** to use JavaScript. Currently we are "hacking" by using the `:target` pseudo element.

Comment: Got it.
Thanks a lot.